# No result for native query in jpa

Tags: sql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have created a native query of following form -

```
@Query(value="SELECT * FROM ORDER_DETAILS WHERE ORDER_ID IS NULL AND tag = ?2 AND CREATED_DATE >= ?3 AND STATUS IN ?1",nativeQuery=true)
    List<Order> findCases(String status, String tag, Date date);
```

where in my case the parameters are as follows -

```
String status="('ACCEPTED')";
String tag="0";
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.add(Calendar.DATE, -5);
Date date =c.getTime();
```

On executing the query i dont empty output. But when i execute the same query(written below) on oracle, i get the required result.

```
SELECT * FROM ORDER_DETAILS WHERE ORDER_ID IS NULL AND TAG = '0' AND CREATED_DATE >='23-11-2018'  AND ORDER_STATUS IN ('ACCEPTED');
```

Can anyone tell what i did wrong?

Comment: Have you tries `AND STATUS IN (?1) `  and String status="ACCEPTED";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use an *in* clause then there's not much point having a single String as a param.

```
@Query(value="SELECT * FROM ORDER_DETAILS WHERE ORDER_ID IS NULL 
                  AND tag = ?2 AND CREATED_DATE >= ?3 
                     AND STATUS IN ?1", nativeQuery=true)
List<Order> findCases(List<String> statuses, String tag, Date date);

List<String> statuses = new ArrayList<>();
statuses.add("ACCEPTED");
String tag="0";
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.add(Calendar.DATE, -5);
Date date = c.getTime();

List<Order> order = repo.findCases(statuses, tag, date);
```